# Laptop CPU underclocked when running a low end game

Tags: laptop, windows-10, cpu

I want to give my laptop specs before asking my question :

> Serial Number : 2CE31506NP
>
> Product Number : D9UI7EA#ABF
>
> Manufacturer : HP
>
> Processor : Intel Core I7-3610QM 2.30 GHZ
>
> OS : Windows 10 Familial (Upgraded from Windows 8)

---

**While running google chrome and little apps**
[image: While running google chrome and little apps]

---

**While running Battlenet And Hearthstone and google (multitasking)**
[image: While running Battlenet And Hearthstone and google (multitasking)]

My PC ran fine a months ago and now I don't know what is going on. Does anyone have a clue about this?

Comment: Be sure your power settings are correct, your processor can boost it's frequency up to 3.3 GHz, but it must be allowed to do so by the OS.  If it is not running at that speed it either is running hot enough it wants to clock itself to below its base frequency to allow time to cool itself off, or your power settings are preventing it from doing so.

Answer (score 3):

You CPU has a technology known as [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) which is an Intel technology that allows the CPU to overclock itself when the CPU is ***not*** at its thermal limits.

When browsing the web your CPU will only be lightly used and so can quickly boost up above its "base" clock of 2.3GHz to 3+ GHz where it will quickly get the job done and settle back down to a lower clock and cool down again.

Playing a game though *will* heat the CPU up quite quickly and it will quickly reach its thermal ceiling and therefore will begin to boost much less or not at all.  In your case it appears to be going to "not at all".

Things to check would be to make sure your cooling vents are clear of dust and that your CPU heatsink is firmly attached.  Open up the laptop if possible to clear out the fans.

If nothing else a cooling mat will help cool the CPU and therefore allow it to boost higher.

Comment: I've opened my laptop a week ago and cleared it of all dust and a months ago he never did this when i was playing hearthstone i don't  know what i can do

Comment: Them you may need to disassemble the heatsink to remove and replace the thermal compound with something better (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Arctic-Silver-Thermal-Compound-3-5g-x/dp/B000OGX5AM) or replace the fans.  The only other alternative is, as I mentioned, a cooling mat with fans in it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. +1 for the feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong.

1) The image says 
'Maximum Speed: 2,3 ghz". Therfore it is not underclocked, just not fully in use.

Also, it says 'CPU @ 2.30 GHZ.

I am assuming that the CPU IS OVERCLOCKED when running chrome. If not, then task manager is not working.

Comment: I want to know why my CPU is slowing when i am launching hearthstone the reverse should happen and i want to know why my CPU is not using 100 % of his capcity

Comment: That's not what the question is asking.